# Jenkins multi-configuration project doesn't aggregate test results

Tags: junit, jenkins, hudson, multi-configuration

I have a multi-configuration project set up to run FF and IE selenium tests. However, it's not aggregating the test results.

If I look at the Project Page I see this:

[image]

---

If I go into a specific build I see this:

[image]

---

But if I click on one of those specific configuration names I see this:

[image]

---

Is there a way to get these results to aggregate? (I have the aggregate downstream results project configuration checkbox checked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently a [Jenkins bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-7976)- Kohsuke Kawaguchi specifically replied to this bug on Aug/31/2011 in the IRC channel [(logs - start @ [21:54:47])](http://echelog.matzon.dk/logs/browse/jenkins/1314741600). Here are the work around responses from those two links:

From the Bug page >>

> You can workaround this by explicitly specifying the jobs to aggregate, rather than relying on the downstream builds logic, and specifying the matrix axes (in quotes) explicitly - i.e., NonMatrixJob,"MatrixJob/label=l_centos5_x86" - the quotes in case of commas in your axis.

From the IRC Log >>

> I did verify that explicitly specifying the list of jobs to aggregate test results from and using the fully qualified job name, including axis, did the trick, but it's a shame that I can't get the auto-discovery from the downstream jobs working.